# Subnetting/VLSM Help

Tags: ip, subnet

i'm having trouble creating a IP Adressing Scheme, I have been given 15 sites each of these are connection via MPLS or leased line. 
For the first site I have determined I need 1700 nodes my tutor also said it requires 50 WAN links and 70 subnets (But I don't understand the reason for this)

I have got an IP address of 128.16.0.1 /21 and a mask of 255.255.248.0

Am I right in thinking that leaves me 21 bits left, making it a /21 network with a max of 2046 hosts?

I'm using a Class B network but am not quite sure if that is big enough, if not I would change it to Class A ?

The problem am having is how can I calculate the IP scheme and how many hosts I can have one each one?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: Have a look here it may help http://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst this does sound like homework (you mentioned your tutor.. dead giveaway) .. Read [How does IPv4 Subnetting Work?](https://serverfault.com/questions/49765/how-does-subnetting-work) and then it should be a bit easier.. That's a really good explanation imho.

Right.  The second point.  Nobody uses classfull networks any more.  You're talking about a Class B network.. That doesn't really exist any more.. Everything is referred to by its netblock size, so Class C is /24, Class B is /16, Class A is /8.

Also, remember that the usable hosts on any network is -2 of the size of the available network, ie, you need one address as the network address, usually the .0 address, ie in 192.168.1.0 ("a class C network"), then your network address is .0, and you need broadcast too, which is, in this case, 192.168.1.255, and then you have 253 usable hosts, (.1 to .254)

Comment: "Nobody uses classfull networks any more."???  A lot of people make this statement but if you assign a static ip address to a Windows machine it sure looks like Microsoft is using the old classful rules to determine a mask.  I agree that it is better to use the prefix, but is anyone confused about what the prefix is when you say Class X?

Comment: That's because Microsoft are still behind the times. ;)